# Getting error while running Longest Flow Path for catchment

Tags: arc-hydro, hec-geohms, error-010067

I am getting the following error while executing the Longest Flow Path for Catchments in Arc Hydro Tools. The tool requires a catchment shapefile which is in float and other file is flow direction (not in float). Both of these files were created using the HEC and ArcHydro tools.

Any way to solve this problem?

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (ox80041098): ERROR 010236: Error in building VAT.
>   ERROR 010067: Error in executing grid expression
>   at
>   ESRI.ARCGIS>GeoAnalyst.RasterCOnversionOpClass.ToRasterDataset(IGeoDataset dataset, String rasterFormat, IWorkspace pWorkspace, String name)
>   at
>   ESRI.APWR.ApHydro.ArcHydroOp.LongestFlowPathforCatchment(ApLayers aplayers, Int32 debug, ITrackCancel& trackcancel, IGPMessages&messages, Strings& exMessage) in
>   CBuilds\9s]ArcHydroTools\src\ApHydroOp.vb:line 68183

[image: example]

Comment: What did you find when you looked up those error numbers?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I've made the changes as asked for. Now, I have looked up on the internet regarding this system runtime error, and other people have faced similar problems, but I haven't found anything related to error 010236. Their respective system runtime error was related to path and storing data on a network drive. I work on my laptop, so I don't have a network drive, and as far as the path concerned, I don't know what to do with that. And there is no error log file as such to get details.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button to provide any additional details relevant to the question.  Are you using an integer grid (which can have a VAT) or a floating point grid which cannot?  What are all the parameter values that you supplied to the tool to get this error?

Comment: Have you reviewed https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=error+010236 for ideas?

Comment: I have made the edits as asked for, and as for the link you provided, it's a tool, so I don't know how to access the code running in the background.

Comment: I have also experienced the same problem now with ArcHydro 10.7. Please what can I do?